# menukeys error option clash package color

Tags: menukeys

as you can see I use a list of packages but when I try to use the **menukeys** package, I get an error as a result

```latex
\documentclass[14pt]{extbook}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[pass,paperwidth=8.5in,paperheight=11in]{geometry}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\let\clipbox\relax
\usepackage[os=win]{menukeys} %error latex

\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{28,138,207}
```

> **error**

```latex
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package color.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.78 \SetupKeyvalOptions
                        {family=mdf,prefix=mdf@}
?
```

Comment: The package you want to load is `xcolor`, not `color`.

Comment: And the `usenames` option has been deprecated for quite a few years: it's the default.

Comment: but i use this type of code `\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{28,138,207}`

Comment: @royer And?... This shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @frougon  yes, I believe I found the solution and I will publish it as an answer to my question and I hope it helps others who may have a similar problem.

Comment: I get no error with your snippet on a current tex system.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple, you only have to **delete the package** `\usepackage[usenames]{color}`for this`\usepackage{xcolor}` and I think it would look like this:

````
\documentclass[14pt]{extbook}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[pass,paperwidth=8.5in,paperheight=11in]{geometry}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xcolor} % ----------------> package changed
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\let\clipbox\relax
\usepackage[os=win]{menukeys} %error latex

\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{28,138,207}```
````